Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp. targetSDK=34 requires permissions
I am doing screen recording and getting the error below
Unable to start service com.hbisoft.hbrecorder.ScreenRecordService@67f055a with Intent { cmp=com.call.santa.prank.sound/com.hbisoft.hbrecorder.ScreenRecordService (has extras) }: 

java.lang.SecurityException: Starting FGS with type microphone callerApp=ProcessRecord{74cd2f9 22442:com.call.santa.prank.sound/u0a548} targetSDK=34 requires permissions: 

all of the permissions allOf=true [android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE] 

any of the permissions allOf=false 

[android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_HOTWORD,

android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT, 

android.permission.CAPTURE_MEDIA_OUTPUT, 

android.permission.CAPTURE_TUNER_AUDIO_INPUT, 

android.permission.CAPTURE_VOICE_COMMUNICATION_OUTPUT, 

android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO]  

The problem only occurs on "some android 14 devices". and the app must be in the eligible state/exemptions to access the foreground only permission.
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MEDIA_PROJECTION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_MICROPHONE"/>

I tried some solutions on stackoverflow but it didn't work. I also added permissions to Manifest

In Android 14 you have to start Notification before start foreground service and after close foreground service you have to close notification
so please start the notification.

@Jojo YoLo, Can you be more specific? how can i do it

mention all the solution in below in "Answer" part

Before start service "ScreenRecordService" start Notification
private fun createNotificationChannel() {
    val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
        CHANNEL_ID,
        "Recordin Service Channel",
        NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
    )
    val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
    manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
}

private fun createNotification(): Notification {
    return NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Screen Capture")
        .setContentText("Recording screen...")
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground) // Use your app's icon
        .build()
}

now call above function in override fun onStartCommand(...) on top like below
createNotificationChannel()
startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification())


Can you explain more clearly why it is necessary to do so, is there any documentation about this, I tried searching but no results @Jojo YOLO

Yes, it is required on Android 14 and later for security reasons; certain apps use foreground services and collect data without the user's knowledge, thus you can no longer do so. Foreground Service
